# Does the remote control plugin work with Grails 3?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Does the remote control plugin work with Grails 3?

https://grails.org/plugin/remote-control

I see references to fixes for grails 2.4 on the product page but nothing for 3.

-Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be supported by Grails 3.x (yet). You can find all of the Grails 3 plugins over on [bintray](https://bintray.com/grails/plugins).

And in this case, this plugin uses a custom repository at http://dl.bintray.com/alkemist/maven/ which doesn't appear to have a Grails 3 compatible version.